# How to group JsonArray result content in json index

Tags: php, json, object

In my JsonArray result, I want to put all the content in index `[{'data':{contenthere}}]`

Here is my code :

```
$data = [];
$gr = []; //some data here

foreach($gr as $g) {
    $data[] = [
        'id'   =>  $g['id'],
        'name'   =>  $g['name'],
        'phone'   =>  $g['pĥone']
   ]
}

return $data;
```

return `$data` output :

```
string(249) "[
    {
        "id": "112",
        "name": "john",
        "phone": "XXXXXXXXX"
    },
    {
        "id": "213",
        "name": "mike",
        "phone": "XXXXXXXXX"
    },
    {
        "id": "246",
        "name": "jess",
        "phone": "XXXXXXXXX"
    },
]
```

cool, now I want to put all this in `['data']` so the result needed :

```
string(249) "[
    {
        "data": {
          {
            "id": "112",
            "name": "john",
            "phone": "XXXXXXXXX"
          },
          {
            "id": "213",
            "name": "mike",
            "phone": "XXXXXXXXX"
          },
          {
            "id": "246",
            "name": "jess",
            "phone": "XXXXXXXXX"
          },
        }
    }
]
```

As [Google JSON Style](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsoncstyleguide.xml#data.previous_/_data.previousLink)

I tried the `$data[]['data']` but the `"data":` repeats in each object

```
foreach($gr as $g) {
        $data[]['data'] = ...
```

I thought do do `group_by` function but I think that there is a simple solution for that

Comment: So try `$data['data'][]`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I also tried that but the `'data':` is not displayed even for each object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you really need the extra array at the top level, but use...

```
return [["data" => $data]];
```

should give you the result.

Answer (score 0):

Use [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to achieve this:

```
$json = json_encode(array('data' => $data));
print_r($json);
```

Result:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "112",
      "name": "john",
      "phone": "XXXXXXXXX"
    },
    {
      "id": "213",
      "name": "mike",
      "phone": "XXXXXXXXX"
    },
    {
      "id": "246",
      "name": "jess",
      "phone": "XXXXXXXXX"
    }
  ]
}
```